# SQL Server: Multiple OUTPUT clauses in MERGE causing issue

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to insert or update data in table using Merge statement. after insert and update i want to store something into temp table.

this way i tried.

```
 CREATE TABLE #Tmpdata  
 (  
  ID INT,  
  LineItem VARCHAR(MAX)  
 )  
  
MERGE INTO TblLineItemTemplate Trg    
   USING     
   (    
    SELECT value as LineItem FROM STRING_SPLIT(@CommaSeparatedItems, ',')  
   ) AS Src     
   ON UPPER(TRIM(Trg.LineItem)) = UPPER(TRIM(Src.LineItem)) AND Trg.TickerID = @TickerID    
    
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN     
    INSERT     
    (    
     TickerID,    
     LineItem,    
     Action,    
     InsertedOn    
    )    
    VALUES     
    (    
     TRIM(@TickerID),     
     TRIM(Src.LineItem),     
     'I',     
     GETDATE()    
    )    
    OUTPUT inserted.LineItemId,inserted.LineItem  INTO #Tmpdata(ID,LineItem)

    WHEN MATCHED THEN     
    UPDATE SET Trg.Action= 'U'
    OUTPUT Deleted.LineItemId,Deleted.LineItem  INTO #Tmpdata(ID,LineItem);
```

When compiling above code then getting error that **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.**

if i remove last  **WHEN MATCHED THEN** then code is getting compiled. please guide me where i made the mistake in code. Thanks

Comment: A `MERGE` can only have *one* `OUTPUT` clause, and it goes at the end, as shown in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) shows. Honestly, I suggest having a read of [So, you want to use MERGE, eh?(https://sqlblog.org/merge) (you at least want that `HOLDLOCK` hint in there), but if you actually *need* 2 `OUTPUT` clauses, then an Upsert route would be a much better path anyway,

Comment: if i use one OUTPUT then how could i store inserted id and updated id into temporary table. please share some idea with code example. i am not aware about Upsert routine.

Comment: *"please share some idea with code example."* The aforementioned [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) has plenty of [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#examples), including ones with the `OUTPUT` clause; what were wrong with those?

Comment: @Ramesh Dutta Long story short, you can use both "horizontally": `OUTPUT inserted.LineItemId,inserted.LineItem,deleted.LineItemId,deleted.LineItem  INTO #Tmpdata(newID,newLineItem,oldID,oldLineItem)`